# Запрос для вывода записей, начинающиеся на определенные буквы

Tags: sql

Нужно вывести записи, которые начинаются на буквы П и Н, с одной буквой понятно:

`` SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'П%' ``

а как с несколькими буквами?

Comment: попробуйте через or, должно получится

Comment: П и Н или всё же П или Н?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'П%' or name LIKE 'Н%'
```

Comment: действительно, так просто
спасибо)